# Removing a tag from custom post type loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops

I am currently using this code below to display all the pages in my category:

```
      <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
      <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
       <?php echo "<div class='col-md-6' style='margin-bottom:20px;'>"; ?>
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopr"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'categoryimage', array('class' => 'testclass')); ?> </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 categorytiletext2">
                  <div class="testdiv">
                       <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                       <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                 </div>
           </div>
     </div>
     <?php echo "</div>"; ?>

</a>
<!-- If there is no posts, display an error message -->
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
      <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- If there is no posts, display an error message -->
```

This works really well, but I have now added tags to these pages. What I need to do, is remove certain tags from the loop. For example, my tag is called maintag.

I have tried to add the following:

```
  <?php $my_query = new WP_Query(array('tag__not_in'=>array('maintag'), 'category_name'=>'Clients', 'orderby'=>'title', 'order'=>'ASC')); ?>
```

but this didn't work.

Does this need to be done by ID's?

EDIT:

New Code, still not working??

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
      <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php $tag_object = get_term_by('slug', 'sector1', 'post_tag');
$tagID = $tag_object->term_id;


$my_query = new WP_Query(array('tag__not_in'=> array($tagID), 'category_name'=>'Clients', 'orderby'=>'title', 'order'=>'ASC')); ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
       <?php echo "<div class='col-md-6' style='margin-bottom:20px;'>"; ?>
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopr"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'categoryimage', array('class' => 'testclass')); ?> </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 categorytiletext2">
                  <div class="testdiv">
                       <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                       <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                 </div>
           </div>
     </div>
     <?php echo "</div>"; ?>

</a>
<!-- If there is no posts, display an error message -->
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
      <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- If there is no posts, display an error message -->
```

Comment: Use `pre_get_posts` to remove posts with a certain tag from the loop on your category pages

Comment: Sorry, where would I use that?

Answer (score 0):

if `maintag` is slug then use `'slug'` in first parameter if it is `name` then use `'name'` instead of slug

link: [get_term_by()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

```
$tag_object = get_term_by('slug', 'maintag', 'post_tag');
$tagID = $tag_object->term_id;


$my_query = new WP_Query(array('tag__not_in'=> array($tagID), 'category_name'=>'Clients', 'orderby'=>'title', 'order'=>'ASC'));
```